# Disabling all gameobjects in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm having difficulties while trying to disable all gameobjects in my array. I used Debug.Log to check if DisableGuns() runs and it does. Here is the code (C#).

```
void DisableGuns()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < weapons.Length; i++)
    {
        weapons[i].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

I also tried it like this:

```
foreach(GameObject obj in weapons)
{
    obj.SetActive(false);
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Double check the _content_ of `weapons`. Log out its `Length` and double check that the items in it are the game objects you expect them to be. Your code, as it stands, is correct so it's likely some wiring/population issue outside the code.

Comment: I just tried dragging the gameobjects in the array again and suddenly it worked. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Mark Chris' answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Double check the content of `weapons`. Your code, as it stands, is correct so it's likely some wiring/population issue outside the posted code.